# Jenkins GIT Multibranch plugin - PR

Tags: git, jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

We use `Jenkins multibranch git jobs` for various branches, some of them are **open**, allowing any user to directly push source code. However, our master branch follows a **closed** policy, permitting code merges only through a `PR` with successful unit tests run.

This approach generally works well, except for one specific scenario:
There are some cases with updates in both `Jenkinsfile` and `source code` which are **interdependent**. An old `Jenkinsfile` might not build updated `source code`, and vice versa. The problem arises when we create a `PR` from a branch with such **interdependent** updates to the master branch. The triggered build on the master branch continues to use its old `Jenkinsfile`, which then tries to build the updated source code from the `PR` branch — leading to build failures.

Is there a way to make the master branch use the `Jenkinsfile` from the `PR` branch to avoid this issue?

**Note:**
That's what the entire process looks like. Participants:

1. `Azure Repos Git`
2. `Azure DevOps Pipeline`. The setup is in the first image
3. `Jenkins multibranch job`. The setup is in the second image

Whenever a user attempts to create a pull request for their changes into the master branch of `Azure Repos Git`, it initiates the execution of an `Azure DevOps pipeline`. This pipeline is relatively straightforward; its sole purpose is to trigger a `Jenkins multibranch job`. Subsequently, the `Jenkins multibranch job` is executed. If it successfully completes, we proceed to perform the actual merge of the pull request.

A challenge arises in this process: The `Azure DevOps Pipeline` is set up to trigger the master branch, which means it always triggers the execution of the `Jenkinsfile` located in the master branch, rather than the one in the `PR` branch. However, it's important to note that the `Jenkins` job, in the `Declarative: Checkout SCM` step, checks out the changes from the `PR` branch. That makes the build inconsistent - we have master's Jenkinsfile and pull request branch's source code.

**Azure Devops pipeline configuration**
[image: Azure Devops pipeline configuration]

**Jenkins multibranch job configuration**
[image: Jenkins multibranch job configuration]

Comment: You are triggering builds of `master` when a PR is submitted to merge changes into `master`, is that right?

Comment: I'm lost about what _"The triggered build"_ means. Is it a pre-merge or a post-merge build. If it is a post-merge, there is NO reason for Jenkins to use the old Jenkinsfile.

Comment: @YSC Yes, that's exactly what is happening. I'm triggering a pre-merge build to check if the changes that we are trying to merge to master are ok. If not, then PR gets rejected, otherwise, the changes get merged to the master. Sorry for confusing you

Comment: No worries. Could you share how that pre-merge build is done? What git commit is checked-out exactly? Is a temporary merge with master done locally on the build environment?

Comment: @YSC I tried to extend the description and make it somehow more clear.. The additional details are posted in the Note section